# After waking up from sleep, why are all my windows the wrong size?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I have a Windows 7 64-bit laptop. Frequently, but not always, when it wakes up from sleep the windows have all been resized to a much smaller size than they were before. It's a real pain having to resize them all to a usable size again.

Why might this be happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because someone resized them while you were sleeping.

Comment: Your eyes aren't fully open yet. It will look right after a cup of coffee.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/453446/how-can-i-stop-windows-re-positioning-after-waking-from-sleep

Comment: and this, if you are NVIDIA card owner:  sites.google.com/site/ebobster/stuff/displayportblanking

Answer (score 0):

This may be down to windows changing the resolution when the screen switches off.  It shouldn't happen, but I could imagine Windows doing something silly like deciding that the monitor suddenly can't handle more than 640x480 or something when the monitor gets put to sleep.

If it is doing this you would find all the windows shrunk and gathered together in one place.

I have no idea how you'd go about stopping this though - maybe make sure you have the latest video and monitor drivers installed may help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange thing to happen. I would try hibernating your PC instead of setting it to sleep (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions). It shouldn't be happening, but in terms of a quick fix, I would try this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been asked a while back. I had a similar issue, so I'm posting my solution for whoever else runs into the same issue.

The problem is in your **video driver**. They coded it without accounting for the system entering the suspended state. Unfortunately it's a common issue with Windows drivers. When they test the driver, some developers don't think about testing it for when your system enters sleep or hibernation. So there's basically a bug in the video driver. (May also happen in any other driver: *network card*, *mouse*, *keyboard*, you name it.)

So the solution is to **update the video driver**. For that go to the site of the manufacturer of your computer ([Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/) for instance) and download it from there. (Note that such driver will most certainly not be available via Windows update.)

PS. And no, this is not a Windows issue. It's a hardware vendor who's to blame here.