# How can I stop windows re-positioning after waking from sleep?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I put my multi-monitor system to sleep when it's not in use. After I wake it up, all windows are repositioned to a different screen. The closest pattern I can think of is that the windows there were on the main screen switch to a the second screen. It looks like it disconnects the main screen before it goes to sleep which in turn switches all the windows to the 2nd or 3rd screen.

Edit: Here's the video card I'm using --> SAPPHIRE FleX 100322FLEX Radeon HD 6450

Comment: You need to specify the graphics adapters you're using, this is probably their fault.

Comment: I found the definitive solution to this: do as Stephen,  ([st99](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/26dac9c7-4df1-4607-8551-6633fdc2673d)), says [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/windows-10-multiple-display-windows-are-moved-and/2b9d5a18-45cc-4c50-b16e-fd95dbf27ff3) in the ninth answer

Comment: same issue is on kubuntu, anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: Unable to add as an answer, but having read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/849327/103148) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1003820/103148), I found the solution to be a manipulation of HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration. With all additional monitors disconnected, delete all keys at this path and restart PC. Note new key added to this path (A). Reconnect monitors and note further new key added (B). Set up display settings as desired. New key will be added again (C). Each key represents a display config. Delete the undesired key (probably key B).

Comment: I've had a couple PCs at work experiencing this issue. Both were Windows 10. First had Intel HD Graphics 530 and the new one as of a couple days ago has Intel UHD Graphics 630. I didn't have this issue at all with Intel driver 22.20.16.4771, then Windows automatically updated to 24.20.100.6344 and I started noticing the issue. Rollback fixed it. Two times after that, Windows automatically updated to 25.20.100.6446, the issue came back, I rolled back to resolve it. New PC has 26.20.100.7262 and has the same issue. I'm trying to find a solution since I can't simply roll back to 22.20.16.4771.

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer to this. The answer you mention does not solve the problem for me.

Comment: I did two things, 1. use the Intel software (Dell Latitude 5490, circa 2019, Intel graphics, Win10) and set all the monitors' resolutions to Full instead of Default.  2. the solution by st99 quoted by @SoldeplataSaketos above, delete all the greyed-out Monitors in Device Manager (devmgmt.msc).  Seems to be fixed.  Haven't rebooted yet ;-)

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos The answer provided by st99 in the forum you shared seems to have solved the issue in my case.

Comment: @SoldeplataSaketos I was also helped by your pointer to st99's reply above.

Comment: This still happens on windows 10. I have 2 DELL 27 inch and 3 Samsung 22 inch. The videos card is a Radeon Rx 590 and I have updated the software and the drivers and placed all monitors on my graphics card, was using also a monitor extender. Seams to be working fine if I wake the pc after 1-2 mins but after 1-2 hours has some issues. I am also using multiple desktops (the native feature from windows 10). I am looking for a software that also memorizes on startup the window position for multiple desktops. Display Fusion and other seam to fail with overload or not proper detection.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue is most likely with the graphics driver.  Whenever a single monitor is disconnected from a multimonitor setup in Windows, Windows will attempt to move everything from that screen onto the remaining screen(s).  Usually, this will not occur when suspending/hibernating/shutting down the computer.  Thus, it is probably because of the graphics driver doing one of the following:

- 'Disconnecting' the monitors when you put the computer to sleep, so when Windows awakens, it must re-determine where to place everything.
- Recognizing the monitors in a different order each time you bring the computer out of sleep, forcing Windows to rearrange your application windows.

Check to see if there is an update to your graphics driver by going to the chipset manufacturer's website.

Comment: FYI: My drivers are from Intel, so I presumed they were signed and distributed with Windows Updates, but they were not.

Comment: Similar problem here. I have a Dell laptop with nVidia graphics adapter. Installing a newer driver from nVidia instead of the Dell driver fixed the problem.

Comment: similar Problem here. latest OEM Intel HD 4600 drivers. may be I should check Drivers from PC Vendor (HP)?

Comment: Same problem with a 7i5bnk NUC - got latest intel drivers

Answer (score 74):

This is an old question, but if anyone arrives here with the same issue, I suggest trying the solution posted here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa

I'm running Windows 8.1 with two 2560x1440 displays on DisplayPort. When waking from sleep, all my windows had been pushed to one display, and some of them resized. This fixes the issue for me; now all my window positions and sizes are preserved. Here is the relevant link content:

> I have found a work-around. Using Sysinternals ProcessMonitor I found
>   that Windows was accessing the following Registry path:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration`
>
> My system had three entries:
>
> - `DELF003YY7707BR0MUL_30_07D7_6A^9A3774EB79DEE3E3E38496CC7DF4D936`
> - `QHD32000001_31_07D6_D5^63E1ABDD175E7871DCAEB710418A0F75`
> - `SIMULATED_8086_2A42_00000000_00020000_1010100^CDE365D1B3F0942F0CF38BFB8E127AB4`
>
> Under each is a tree called `00`. Two of the keys are:
>
> - `PrimSurfSize.cx`
> - `PrimSurfSize.cy`
>
> Under `00` was another branch also called `00`. Two of the keys are:
>
> - `ActiveSize.cx`
> - `ActiveSize.cy`
>
> In the first two configs (i.e. `DELF00...` & `QHD3...`), the above keys
>   were 1440x900, so they were not involved.
>
> The third (`SIMULATED...`) were set to 1024x768.
>
> I changed these to 1600x900 and the problem was solved.
>
> Further I changed resolution (via control panel) to 1920x1080, the
>   moving/resize issue returned, but the lower right corner was set to
>   1600x900, ie the `SIMULATED...` settings.
>
> So for some reason one of the configs does not get set correctly.
>
> I don't know why there are three configs, I have only ever used one
>   monitor.

Comment: This sort of works for me. I have a 4K monitor with 175% scaling and setting these makes it behave as though the simulated monitor is without scaling (windows are resized to a maximum of 100/175 of the screen size).

Comment: Simply delete the whole HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration, it works as well and it's faster.

Comment: My laptop doesn't have a SIMULATED key. I'm new to Windows 10 and I'm wondering if it's been removed? If not, is there a way to get it into my system?

Comment: Deleting the entry does not work for me (Windows 10). As soon as I turned of the monitor, the 'SIMULATED' entry is created again. Original solution works (ie. modify each occurrence of 1024,768 with actual resolution).

Comment: Here's another related post I found on Microsoft Answers for Windows 10.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/windows-10-multiple-display-windows-are-moved-and/2b9d5a18-45cc-4c50-b16e-fd95dbf27ff3

Comment: Deleting the whole configuration as @OlafM suggested works perfectly. In my case, windows hat about 30 entries. After rebooting, only one was re-recreated, containing only the monitors I have actually plugged int.

Comment: I was nervous about deleting everything in the Configuration folder but I made an export first and deleting everything fixed the issue, after resume I had to set the monitor order and it no appears fixed.

Comment: This worked for me on my 7i5bnk nuc (I definitely have latest graphics drivers - the newest driver didn't fix the issue).

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I had a good dozen entries under Configuration.  One of them had my primary monitor at 640x480, probably due to a failed monitor type detection at some point.  Apparently it was always using that as the default and thus screwing up the size and position of everything.  I deleted just that one configuration and so far afterwards everything has been fine.  By the way, I have a Surface Book 2 with Surface Dock, and I used to shut down at home, then start back up at the office.  Now I undock and power up/down separately, and that has eased the monitor problems too.

Comment: Alas, I spoke too soon.  The problem returned not long after.  Oddly, though, showing hidden devices in the Device Manager revealed a 640x480 monitor which I've just uninstalled.  Maybe that'll fix the problem...but I have a terrible feeling that monitor will come back.

Comment: I have no SIMULATED Configuration entry and modifying/deleting entries+rebooting had **no effect**.

Comment: No need for all this modifying of entries at this path. Just delete all keys and then follow the steps in my comment [here](https://superuser.com/questions/453446/how-can-i-stop-windows-re-positioning-after-waking-from-sleep#comment2236572_453446).

Comment: Deleting the Configuration key seems to have done the trick. Hopefully it sticks. I haven't rebooted since deleting it about 4 days ago.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Got back from lunch and my primary and secondary monitors switched places. Windows thought my left (primary) monitor was actually my right (secondary) monitor. All my windows were moved to the new primary monitor (physically right, virtually left). If this happens anywhere near as frequently as the issue I was trying to fix, this is worse.

Comment: I first deleted all the configuration values but this didn't work for me. So I rebooted and saw a single folder (GSM5A...) in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration. I then locked the screen and waited until the display turned off. After waking the computer, another folder (NOEDID_...) was created. I then copied ALL the values from GSM5A.. to NOEDID_.. and put the display to sleep again. This time, it woke and my windows all seemed to have maintained their size and positions.

Comment: @rein That worked for me. (Single 4K display, intel graphics 530, windows 7.) Deleted all Configuration keys, rebooted and had single display config. After a sleep mode, a NOEDID... appeared. Changed the ActiveSize.cx (and .cy) keys from 1024 and 764 values to 3840 and 2160. Also the PrimSurfSize.cx (and .cy) keys.

Comment: The folder name changed from SIMULATED_... to NOEDID_... in recent / current versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I have a 4K monitor as my main, and a 1280x1024 monitor as my secondary. The 4K monitor is of course at 150% scaling while the other is at 100%. Every time the 4K monitor is turned off, windows are moved and resized, and there is no "SIMULATED" or "NOEDID" entry to modify. Quite frankly, this is incredibly frustrating and should not be a thing.

Comment: Forgot to mention that my 4K monitor is connected via HDMI and not DP.

Comment: I just tried again with the 4K monitor scaling set to 100%, and the result is the same. (I can't edit my comment to append this information because there is a time limit.)

Comment: This response led me to a resolution.  I had a lot of entries and as such, it was hard to figure out which configurations were important. I deleted the whole HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration folder, then let the machine go to sleep.  After waking it up, I had 2 new entries.  I compared the 2 entries and found that one monitor was missing during power save simulation.  After enabling HDMI Compatibility in the monitor's settings, everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 21):

If your computer has Intel HD Graphics you have to set Extend Display options (and resolution settings) from the Intel Graphics Control Panel. If you do it from the Windows Display settings it will reset after you wake it from sleep mode.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It didn't change anything for me. Or do I have to completely wipe the windows settings before doing it with the Intel software?

Comment: It worked for me after I reset the settings and then applied from the Intel graphics.

Comment: I merely switched some option and then reverted it back. It enabled the "apply" bouton and saved the config from the driver. Works great after manual lock. I wll see what happens after a long period

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 and saved my sanity.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on my Windows 10 Dell Inspiron

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away after I disabled the integrated Intel graphics adapter in Device Manager.  I don't need the Intel graphics adapter because I use the AMD Radeon card for my extended dual monitor setup.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

There may be an offical solution for this on the horizon:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/avoid-unexpected-app-rearrangement/

**Please note**: this is currently **only available on Windows 10 insider build 21287** and above.

*I will edit this answer to reflect changes and inclusion in future Windows builds; additional post because it's an entirely different solution.*

Comment: Saw this blog post and also thought to find this old question and post in it, but you beat me to it 

Comment: to check your build: win key > about pc > OS build

Comment: So according to the article it's the displayport that's the culprit. I never thought it could be because of the different ports, as my computer has 1 hdmi port and 3 displayports, so I have no choice but to use it. Although in 2023 with non-insider build 19045.2728, the issue is still persistent.

Comment: still have this issue.
neither this answer, nor the blog post served to help anyone.

Answer (score 10):

I think I found a workaround for this issue by combining the ideas from [these posts](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa?page=15&rtAction=1448170294531).

(my PC is Windows 10 TH2, Intel HD4600 with HDMI port, Changhong 4k monitor)

Here is the procedure.

1. Delete all extra registry entries under ...GraphicDrivers\Configuration and GraphicDrivers\Connectivity, leaving only the entry corresponding to my monitor (MST00301...)
2. Before putting monitor to sleep, just type "WIN" + "D" combo key to minimize all desktop windows.
3. After turning on monitor, type "WIN" + "D" again to restore all windows.

Comment: I think Win+D is not needed. After deleting all the entries and restarting the pc the external monitor is added again to the registration. After that it seems to work as expected. Maybe windows was confused of to many different configurations. In my case I had 12 entries and now there are only 2: https://www.maxrev.de/windows-position-von-apps-im-multi-monitor-betrieb-nach-aufwachen-t366585.htm#pic462673

Comment: This worked for me, but only after correcting the new SIMULATED_ ... key. After the restart, I had two new entries under Configuration and Connectivity. The SIMULATED_ 00 entry had 1024, 768 and 4096 for cx, cy and stride values, which are wrong. I copied just those values from the other key, which appeared to be correct for my monitor, and rebooted. I have a single 40" 4K monitor, a Wasabi Mango UHD400 and problem is now fixed.

Comment: For me, the Win+D trick works, even without altering the registry, which did not work. Note that the Desktop does not have to be minimized: the Desktop icons that are outside the 1024x768 box will not be moved after turning the monitor off and on again. Also, maximized windows do not suffer the resize/move problem.

Comment: For me, Win+D doesn't even restore windows to their previous locations even when hitting it twice in a row *without* anything going to sleep/standby.  It puts *most* of them back to where they were, but many are out of place.  Even different Chrome windows, so it doesn't seem to be application specific.  That's weird, right?

Answer (score 10):

Not all NVidia cards support the ability to fake the EDID, and it isn't just Sleep that causes this problem. If a monitor is turned off or disconnects briefly, it can wreak havoc on a carefully configured screen layout. As none of the solutions here worked out for me, I wrote a utility to restore the window positions when the number of monitors change.  It is available with source code [here](https://github.com/hunkydoryrepair/MonitorKeeper/releases).

Comment: I've tested @GarrGodfrey 's program and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This also seems to work well for me, nothing else seemed to work, I'm on a Legion y540.

Answer (score 5):

I solved with this little application:
https://github.com/hunkydoryrepair/MonitorKeeper/releases

Just run it, and it will be maintain windows in same posizion.
Thank you very much @hunkydoryrepair.

Comment: Totally underrated solution. I love how elegant the solution is. Very simple. It saves window positions bucketed by the number of active screens. If that number goes down, then saving the positions of windows that get combined on fewer screens is isolated from the saved state of the higher number of monitors. When the number of screens increases back up to the original amount, it restores any positions that had been saved there. That works waking from sleep, or KVM switching, etc.

Comment: Commenting to say that this ended up being the solution. To "install" it, I just copied the executable to the root of my C: drive, then made a shortcut and placed that inside of my Startup folder.

Comment: I made a similar program that can save/restore all window positions to JSON text file.  I put the c# source code in a gist.  Use Visual studio to compile it.  It can support multiple configurations. 
 But it is manual, so you need to put shortcuts on desktop for each configuration https://gist.github.com/jdhenckel/129f24228be14df8d0de54ad61c03150

Comment: This is literally my answer that shows up right above this. That's my app. You're welcome

Answer (score 4):

I "solved" this problem with [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com).

It can run triggers on various Windows 10 events, so I told it to save the window positions when the desktop is locked, and restore them when it's unlocked.  See the settings dialog below.

This isn't perfect: When I unlock, I have to wait a few seconds while it moves each window back to its previous position.  But it's a lot better than everything getting stuck on one monitor every time I lock my machine (a dozen times a day or more).

[image: DisplayFusion Settings Dialog - Triggers]

Comment: You saved me, I knew DisplayFusion 'could' do it but I didn't know how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, with three 1920x1080 monitors arranged horizontally, it seems to have been fixed by going to the registry key mentioned in other answers (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration`), finding the key starting with `SIMULATED`, then changing all the values of 1920 under that key to 5760 (1920 times three, for the three monitors).

I'm guessing the `SIMULATED` key is used for when the PC goes to sleep, but Windows still needs to maintain a desktop in the process of going to/resuming from sleep, even when the actual monitor(s) may not report themselves yet.

Comment: This is what helped me the most. Your second paragraph especially seems to be correct. Though I still have windows move to other monitors when the screen is off.

Answer (score 3):

In case none of the solutions above work for you, have a look at

- https://github.com/kangyu-california/PersistentWindows

*works for me*™

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately it still doesn't seem to handle minimized windows - they keep relocating randomly to the primary one on my system of three older 4k Dell P2415Q and one Dell UltraSharp 27 on Quadro P600.. Still I like it better than 30Hz I had to use since 2016 which I described in my answer to this question.

And it takes a lot of blinking for ~2-3 seconds after monitors wake up.

Comment: This caused instability for me waking from sleep, and it didn't specifically handle KVM switches or manual disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here with Windows 8.1 and Macbook Air 2013 (Intel HD Graphics 5000). I try everything. Finally I went to Intel updated with the latest drivers for my graphic card and the problem continues. Then I went to the graphics property, with my second display turn on in Multiple Display I choose 'Disconnect this display', then after the second display disconnected I select extend my desktop and the problem dissapear. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I also have a Macbook Air 2013 with latest drivers and that didn't solve my problem. Do you any ideas how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the fix was https://superuser.com/a/908156/238666 . Summary: Windows fails to read the EDID info from the monitor at wakeup, and in the Nvidia control panel you can save the EDID info to a file and set the pc to read it from that file, under the the Task: Workstation, View System Topology, EDID Source.

In my limited view, the root problem could be the Nvidia card, but also Windows, DisplayPort, or the monitor (Lenovo X1 4K)

Comment: This only works with Quadro cards.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this will be caused by the graphics driver not properly supporting sleep modes and therefore disabling the ability to detect a connected display when the computer goes to sleep.

Update your graphics drivers from the manufacturer to resolve the issue.

If the issue is still not resolved after updating the drivers, it may be due to an unusually reported display ID (EDID). You can usually force the detection of a monitor within the graphics driver control panel.

However if this is unavailable, you can use the Windows Resolution window to detect devices while the monitor is disconnected, then select the display which will report “Another Display Not Connected”, then under Multiple Displays, you can drop down and select “Try to connect anyway” which will broadcast a signal to the monitor over the port type you have selected (the signal will not be interactive), then connect the display which should interpret the signals sent to it properly.

The forced resolution will override detection of the screen and should persist through sleep.

Comment: Do you know a way to enable this setting if the monitor is still connected? I wonder if that will fix my windows slightly moving after wake.

Comment: I tried turning off a monitor (while the VGA cable is still connected) and it disappears from the multiple display configuration in Windows 10. Even after clicking Detect it doesn't give me any way to "Try to connect anyway"... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Like it or not, but according to Dell's known problem with specific 4k monitors link:
http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/19/SLN295708/EN
I had to switch from 59/60Hz to 30Hz on my 3 x Dell P2415Q 4K UHD on Intel 4600 connected with display's stock DP/mDP and it helped me - as Dell KB article says. It applies to UP3214Q and P2715Q too.

The issue didn't manifest on lower res QHD Dell U2515H + same video/PC

Registry keys removal and driver updates were not helping.

Upd 2018/08: And upgrading graphics card to NVIDIA Quadro P600 didn't fix the issue, so staying on 30Hz.

Comment: Urgh, 30Hz is awful to use, so stuttery.

Comment: @SimonEast, it's been a year since I posted this answer and use these 4K-s in 30Hz, being sensitive to fluorescent and LED flickering, and preferring DC 12V Halogen lighting where possible, I'd say 30Hz is OK on these 4K Dell monitors. Youtube action vids are relatively smooth, but I mostly use these screens for code, terminals, mails and chats - don't feel tired after 10-12 hours per day..

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of having 144Hz gaming-grade monitors with fancy VESA certified DP1.4 cables =/

Comment: @OXiGEN Newer Dell Ultrasharp 27" doesn't have this issue. It was specific to these P2415Q back in 2016. 

Those who downvoted my answer need to take their rage to dell :)

Answer (score 0):

[Win Redock](https://github.com/manutalcual/winredock) has worked best for my use case - which was restoring window positions after a display-change. Redock is automatic - saves and restores windows without any intervention. Its open source too.

So if your issue is that your laptop has a display hiccup when it wakes up, this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to simply **install drivers for my newest monitor**.

I have three monitors and this problem was driving me nuts (actually irking me every time I woke my PC, and then I'd forget about it).

When I went about following the instructions for the (highly voted) comment below, I noticed in Device Manager one of my monitors was "Generic PnP Monitor".

> I found the definitive solution to this: do as Stephen, ([st99](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/26dac9c7-4df1-4607-8551-6633fdc2673d)), says [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/windows-10-multiple-display-windows-are-moved-and/2b9d5a18-45cc-4c50-b16e-fd95dbf27ff3) in the ninth answer – Soldeplata Saketos (May 3, 2018 at 8:48 )

*I copy-pasted Stephen's solution in the end of this post, since no one seems to have done it yet.*

I was deleting old unused monitor devices ("Show hidden devices") when I realized my primary monitor (the newest) was the only one without a proper driver.

Now, I don't remember installing manufacturer drivers for my other monitors, buy maybe I did when I installed them.

Once I went to LG's website, downloaded and installed the drivers, I stopped having the problem (tested with 1-minute sleep).

*Or maybe what fixed it for me was deleting the old monitors, as per Stephen's instructions. However, I never rebooted the system. Also, installing the driver seems like a stronger action to me.*

[image: Device Manager with monitors OK, with arrow showing the monitor that used to be "Generic PnP Monitor"]

---

### STEPHEN'S (st99) SOLUTION

> Hello,
>
> I think I may have a solution for this problem.  It appears Windows 10 keeps a history of all the monitors it encounters during its life time.  This includes the basic monitor support during the OS install.  So, if you enable "Show hidden devices" in the Device Manager you will see all the monitors that were connected to your system.
>
> Start the Control Panel as Administrator:
>
> 1. Start Control Panel --> Device Manager
> 2. Select View --> Show hidden devices
> 3. Expand Computer --> Monitors
>    When you expand the Monitors you will see your current monitor (highlighted) and all the disconnected monitors (greyed out).   You may see monitors with "non-PNP" and "PNP" listed as well.  I believe these are aliases to your current monitor (at a lower resolution) before Windows installed drivers for it.
>
> I uninstalled ALL the greyed out monitors.  Right-click on these monitors and select uninstall.  Keep only the highlighted monitor you are currently using.
>
> 4. Uninstall all greyed out monitors (even non-PNP and PNP monitors)
> 5. Reboot your system.
>
> After doing this my windows don't resize after my monitor goes to sleep.  You can quickly test this by temporarily setting your monitor sleep time to 1 minute.
>
> Settings --> System --> Power & Sleep --> Screen [1 minute]
> Cheers,
>
> Stephen