# All windows moving back to primary monitor after waking up from sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, sleep

I have an external monitor connected to my laptop, and I put my laptop to sleep whenever I am not using it. But, upon resuming, all of the windows that were on the *desktop* on my secondary monitor moved to my primary monitor. 
Note that it was only the windows on the desktop that moved; any apps, such as Skype, stayed on the secondary monitor.

I have an Intel HD 4400 graphics card, with (Intel) driver version 10.18.10.3621 (latest).

Does anyone know what is happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: Which driver version are you using? Try the latest driver from Intel (the Windows drivers for the HD4x00 GPUs are rubbish).

Comment: @Jakke Ok, I'm going to try updating, but as of right now, I am using an Intel driver (albeit from December, 2013) and having this issue

Comment: @Jakke as of driver update, problem still persists

Comment: Same issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/453446/how-can-i-stop-windows-re-positioning-after-waking-from-sleep