# Windows 10 windows all return to main monitor on sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, sleep, window

Running Windows 10 Enterprise RTM. With two monitors, after the computer goes to sleep all windows return to main monitor. When only locking the computer and waking it up again windows stay where they should be. The system has two non-sli graphics cards, however both monitors are plugged into the same card.

EDIT: the two monitors are hooked up with DP -> DP on the main monitor and DVI -> HDMI on the second monitor (monitor -> PC).

EDIT2: switched the second monitor to DVI -> DVI, problem still persists.

EDIT3: put the monitors on different, non SLI GPU's, problem still persists

Comment: What connection type are the monitors using? VGA, HDMI, DVI, DP?

Comment: DP->DP on main monitor, DVI->HDMI on second monitor.

Comment: So the monitor they all disappear from is the DVI->HDMI?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Correct

Comment: Can someone with enough rep mark some dups? [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/864593/windows-8-1-64-bit-3-monitors-after-sleep-power-options-then-wake-up-all?lq=1)[similar](https://superuser.com/questions/775499/all-windows-moving-back-to-primary-monitor-after-waking-up-from-sleep?rq=1)[similar](https://superuser.com/questions/805131/windows-get-moved-to-the-primary-monitor-after-waking-from-standby-with-mixed-di?rq=1)

Comment: When I wake up from sleep, all my monitors get shuffled around (I have 3).  Very annoying to put everything back.  I wonder if disconnecting the third will cause similar issues as yours.

Comment: @wjervis I've added a third monitor (lol) now upon waking the windows do sometimes get shuffled around (usually between the main and the one I added) instead of all put on one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

By sleep, do you mean the hard drive goes to sleep, or the monitors go to sleep?

Couple things I would check. I would turn the secondary monitor off by the power button and see if the same thing happens. If the issue doesn't persist. That would mean that Windows 10 has a setting where it turns off all the monitors to conserve power (keep in mind windows 10 was also designed for tablets as well).

You could also change the power settings from power saver to balanced or create your own power settings. (Bear in mind this may or may not work depending on if your IT allows you access to these settings).