# Windows10 fullscreening a window won't actually fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-radeon

I have a multi monitor setup (3, with different resolutions), Windows 10 and AMD R9 380. All drivers/software are up to date. This started to happen after fresh Win7->Win10 installation.

Windows seems to be confused about what the fullscreen dimensions are for certain windows (this chrome window is supposed to be fullscreen):

[image]

A youtube video of the issue: https://youtu.be/jWxywNG8S0k

After locking (Win+L) the current session and logging in after a while, some windows (be it windows explorer or chrome or pdf reader) go in wrong fullscreen size when ordered to go fullscreen. This doesn't happen all the time.

One **temporary fix** is to restart Windows Explorer process from task manager, however I would like to find the cause and fix it. Any ideas as to why this would happen (probably gpu-driver) and how can I permanently fix this?

---

I also have the issue where my main taskbar is shifted to my 2nd monitor (DVI-I) along with all of the open windows from my main monitor (HDMI). This issue is discussed on this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/453446/how-can-i-stop-windows-re-positioning-after-waking-from-sleep) and [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/849327/279815) claims to fix it, but I don't see similar entries in my registry entries after waking up my PC from sleep. For example, I don't have any entry starting with 'SIMULATED_*', probably due to my GPU not being NVIDIA and AMD handles things other way.

This is what I have:

[image]

I can make sense of some abbreviations, but nothing further

- MS - microsoft (as a fallback)
- NIL - not in list (prefix description)
- NOEDID - no Extended Display Identification Data

I cannot see anything related to this misbehavior of windows in any windows options/user preferences or radeon settings options.

Where do I begin to look for a fix for these issues? Has anyone dealt with something similar like these issues and found a fix ?