# How restore windows size after 4k monitor is turned on again?

Tags: windows-10, display, window, 4k-resolution

There are windows 10 and 4k monitor.

**The problem**

1. After moving windows to the corners, each of them takes 1/4 screen size: [image: before monitor turned off]
2. Then monitor is turned off, waits about 20 sec, then turn on it again. And instead of 4 windows there are only 2, each of them take 1/2 screen size:[image: after monitor turned on]
3. And after minimizing these 2 windows, other 2 appear and also take 1/2 screen size:[image]

To the question is - How to save windows size between monitor turning on/off?

Comment: Which type of connection are you using?

Comment: Display port 2.0

Comment: This answer is about the same problem. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/453446/how-can-i-stop-windows-re-positioning-after-waking-from-sleep)

Comment: not helped. :( There is only 1 monitor, and my system does not go to sleep.

Comment: If you're considering using an utility to keep windows position you can try this one. [link](http://www.ninjacrab.com/persistent-windows/). Run it as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This feature appears completely forgotten about in Windows 10 - Thankfully I have had luck with this utility, 'Wilma'. - http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/